# c# check if program runs on startup

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I would like to check if a certain program runs on the computer's startup,i accessed the  `win32 RegistryKey` class for that:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool ok = isOnRegistryStartup("iFilter");
        MessageBox.Show(ok.ToString());
    }
    private bool  isOnRegistryStartup(string key)
    {
       RegistryKey RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
                ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        if (registryKey.GetValue(key)!=null)
        {
            return true;

        }
        return false;

    }
```

The output was `True` indeed,because the program actually runs on the windows startup,but when i disabled that program startup by the `Task manager`(and it's status became `disabled`),the next time i runned the code above the result was still `True`,eventhough that program is not part of the startup programs anymore.

That leads me to a simple conclusion that when the windows task manager disables a startup program,it doesn't delete it's key in the registry key,but it changes another value of it..but i wasn't able to find out what's that changed value.

I hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because setting it disabled on taskmgr doesn't remove its entry in

`CurrentUser\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` but rather setting corresponding value in `CurrentUser\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run` from `0200 0000000...` to `0300 0000 xxxxx....`

Comment: awesome! you just missed somthing it's explorer/StartUpApproved. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just expanding a little bit over what Robert said you should check the following registries:

```
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run32
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run32
```

For the **Run** and **Run32** registries the rule *seems to be*:

- "02 00 00 00..." -> enabled
- any other -> disabled

Comment: when i set a new key,it's also getting done programmatically,using the `SetValue()` method,and i do it on the the  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry...so that's where i'm checking for the value retrieving.. @AlinG
why should i need to check other registry paths?

Comment: You didn't mention that so I did not know if you are also responsible for setting the program as startup. Still, I would do it just to be safe. If you have control over both installation and uninstallation then it's fine if you just remove the key from where you added. This mechanism is pretty undocumented and might not work on older or future versions of Windows so if it was me I would install it as a service.